# Do all versions of Android support the MediaPlayer streaming?

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

As the title says, I'm basically wondering if the MediaPlayer streaming support works for all versions of Android.

Here is the code I'm currently using, which works fine on my Android 2.2 phone:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(SHOUTCAST_STREAM);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

But will that work on say 1.5 or 1.6? Or would I have to build my own buffering management system for the stream?

*** Update ***

Just tested it on the 1.6 emulator, and getting the following errors. On the 2.2 emulator it works fine.

```
23:15:50.074    31  ERROR   PlayerDriver    Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer error (1, -1)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer io error
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at org.me.bla.Bla.onCreate(Bla.java:38)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3502)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:116)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1798)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
23:15:50.074    282 ERROR   MediaPlayer     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So does this mean it just simply doesn't work on on the older versions of the OS, or is there any work around? I guess I could just do a custom buffering system, but I want to make sure there isn't an easier way first.

Comment: What happened when you tried it in the 1.5 and 1.6 emulators?

Comment: @CommonsWare I was thinking about it, but for some reason I thought the emulator wouldn't be able to play sound, which wouldn't allow me to accurately test it. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Also did a bit of reading and it seems to be an issue with the HTTP HEADER. The newer versions of the OS seem to be smart enough to get past that problem, where the older seem to fail.

Comment: I'm also trying to stream a Shoutcast URL. The code is really simple. However, i couldn't get it worked neither with 2.3.3 and 2.3.5. I keep getting Prepare failed.: status=0x1 error. I think, i have some problem with my streaming resource. Could you share your url with me to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Android References](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) the MediaPlayer class has been available since api level: 1 and there isn't anything about it being deprecated. So I would say you would be safe.

On your 1.6 emulator have you started the browser and made sure you can access the internet?

Was the 1.6 emulator one that you have create some time ago? I have had issues with emulators that I have created after a period of time (the files get corrupted). If that is the case you could create a new one.

Another thing I just thought of... Is there some authentication missing somewhere?

I found this [tutorial](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/) that might be helpful as well. He does create a **buffer** in his example.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The reason I asked this question was because I did a bit of reading and saw that there were lots of issues between the different OS versions. So, I wanted to see what other peoples experience has been with it.

Comment: I just tested it and I can access the internet with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the setDataSource. its not reading the file properly. The better way is read by FileInputStream and call getFD() method.Ex:

MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

FileInputStream stream = mContext.openFileInput("string");

mPlayer.setDataSource(stream.getFD());

stream.close();

mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(ANNOUCE_STREAM);

mAndroidPlayer.prepare();

mAndroidPlayer.start();

I think this will help you.

Comment: That requires me to save it into a file and build a whole buffering system around it. The stream I'm talking about is endless - it's not just 1 song. That's basically my last option, if I can't find an easier solution.