# Shoutcast stream work in 2.3 but not in 2.2

Tags: java, android, media-player

my App works very well on android 2.3+ (testing on avd's). But on android 2.2 android mp log me an error

> 01-11 17:47:21.862: E/MediaPlayer(314): error (1, -2147483648) 
>   01-11 17:47:21.891: E/MediaPlayer(314): Error (1,-2147483648)

or

> 01-11 17:50:17.091: E/MediaPlayer(328): error (100, 0) 
>   01-11 17:50:17.103: E/MediaPlayer(328): Error (100,0)

Can someone help me to "decode" those error codes?

My code is very simple, (this is the MediaPlayer part)

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setDataSource(soundUrl);
mp.prepareAsync();

@Override
public void onCreate(MediaPlayer mp) {
mp.start();
}
```

**edit:**
I solved it. I inserted the direct link to the shoutcast directory. It seems that android 2.2 cant resolve the links.

eg: `http://listen.technobase.fm/tunein-dsl-pls` turned into `http://85.17.26.115/`

Comment: does the stream come via HTTPS? Paste the full url of soundUrl

Comment: `soundUrl = http.//www.theradio.cc:8000/trcc-stream.mp3` (get first error)
or
`soundUrl = http://listen.technobase.fm/tunein-dsl-pls` (get second error)

Comment: This maybe of use - it even is from the same source Shoutcast - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574047/do-all-versions-of-android-support-the-mediaplayer-streaming

Comment: Hmm. But why play it in 2.3+ and not in 2.2? mp3 streaming are natively implemented in 2.2

Comment: Did you see the link to the tutorial in the answers area? I really do not know at this point.

Comment: Yeah, I see it. But its a heavy workaround and should work on the other way aswell.

Comment: Testsong worked: `http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3` Seems to be the streamurl is "false"

Comment: How to play SHOUTcast?http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833346/265167

Comment: Thanks, I'am using it already. But I also use the stock mp. :)
Is there any equal to this with OGG streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted the direct link to the shoutcast directory. It seems that android 2.2 cant resolve the links.

eg: `http://listen.technobase.fm/tunein-dsl-pls` turned into `http://85.17.26.115/`